# Elasticsearch NEST API, Searching Multiple Indices

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

If one is seraching several indexes at the same time, is there any way to say that if searching index A, then add this filter and if searching index B then add a different filter.

For example:

```
var filters = new List<Func<QueryContainerDescriptor<PropertySearchResult>, QueryContainer>>();
filters.Add(fq => fq.Term(t => t.Field(f => f.PromoterId).Value(user.Id)));
filters.Add(fq => fq.Term(t => t.Field(f => f.SubscriptionId).Value(subscriptionId)));
string indicies = String.Join(",", Utils.SupportedCountries.Select(c => c.Key.ToLower()).ToArray());
var result = await ElasticSearchConfig.GetClient().DeleteByQueryAsync<PropertySearchResult>(u => u
               .Index(indicies)
               .Query(q => q
               .Bool(bq => bq.Filter(filters))));
```

at the moment, all indices will be subject to the same filters but I would like to vary the filters based on which index is being searched.

Answer (score 0):

Add(with &&) a term query to each of your filters

```
.Term("_index", A)
```

Check this link
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-index-field.html